# Grails & unit test - How to mock below method?

Tags: grails, junit, mocking

I am trying to mock this line but not getting it right

```
 def myList =   myService.withValue("key"){User.getAll()}
```

I am trying to mock like this

```
    def mockMyService = mockFor(owsoo.Myservice, true)

    mockMyService.demand.withValue(1) { key ->

    }
    controller.mockMyService = mockMyService.createMock()
```

I know I am missing something for closure `{User.getAll()}` but can't figure out what exactly to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Closure is passed as parameter only. So this worked

```
myService.demand.withValue(1) { key, Closure cls-> return [abc]
}
```